# Performing CRUD operations in Restful WebService using Java DB - Netbeans

Tags: java, rest, web-services, netbeans, crud

I have the code below

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    package com.service;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.Basic;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    /**
     *
     * @author PCTechRinz
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "DEVELOPER")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Developer.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Developer d"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Developer.findById", query = "SELECT d FROM Developer d WHERE d.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Developer.findByDevname", query = "SELECT d FROM Developer d WHERE d.devname = :devname"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Developer.findByPassword", query = "SELECT d FROM Developer d WHERE d.password = :password")})
    public class Developer implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Integer id;
        @Size(max = 255)
        @Column(name = "DEVNAME")
        private String devname;
        @Size(max = 255)
        @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
        private String password;

        public Developer() {
        }

        public Developer(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getDevname() {
            return devname;
        }

        public void setDevname(String devname) {
            this.devname = devname;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 0;
            hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
            if (!(object instanceof Developer)) {
                return false;
            }
            Developer other = (Developer) object;
            if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "com.service.Developer[ id=" + id + " ]";
        }

    }
```

this is the generated java class after creating Restful Webservice using database in Netbeans but I am having trouble finding the right resources to insert, update and remove data from the database. can anyone give me a guide? will be much appreciated. Thanks. I have tried some answers from previous questions I found in this site but nothing seems to match my needs.

If possible, I want to use the embedded Java DB of netbeans rather than creating MYSQL database .
Hoping I could deliver my thoughts.

Best Regards.

Comment: Insert, Update and Delete I mean CRUD operation codes are not available there. You need to write your custom requirements. But by mean if you want to use then you can use it. Please post your expectations and what you had tried to correct it.

Comment: This is not a help site for general assistance, and _"can anyone give me a guide?"_ is not a specific, answerable question. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please update your question to state a programming problem that you need help with.